# Discovering new subjects on SE

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

When I discovered SE, I naturally joined Q&A sites related to my interests. But now I would like to start learning about a new subject that SE is covering. Is there any feature that I missed that would present basic questions about the subject, something like getting started on that particular subject ? That could be key references, basic questions, awesome answers... I know this does not apply to any subject though (Mathematics e.g.), but this would be an interesting way for new users that don't have questions yet to discover a subject on SE.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Are you asking about learning something new, like first steps to learning C#? Or are you asking about where you can ask questions about another subject?

Comment: Learning something new is best done somewhere else. Just Google something on the Interblags. Tutorials for pretty much anything are abound and you'll eventually find something that will teach you what you want.

Comment: I am talking about stuff like featured topics in forums, where you can get the relevant "getting started" information at a glance. It is impossible in stackoverflow of mathoverflow e.g. but it could be useful on other sites.

Comment: There's community ads on the sidebar of most (all?) SE sites that show interesting recent questions, or you can check the Hot Questions list in the Stack Exchange dropdown at the top right; are those not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Getting Started" subject is rather awkward. Most attempts at phrasing it "How do I start learning X?" or "What books should I read to start doing X?" are considered subjective and not the [good kind of subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

You'd be better off Googling the topic in mind. Get started on whatever tutorial you can find and then when you run into actual problems, ask questions on the related SE site. Asking "How can I get started doing X?" questions on SE will only result in downvotes and "close for off-topic" or "close for not constructive".